# How to connect Mongo DB in a webpack dev server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to connect to Mongo DB using a webpack dev server. While the connection using the node mongodb driver and configuring in server.js is direct and straight forward, I am thinking of a way to do the same using webpack dev server in development (mainly for the hot loading advantage).

I understand that there is a way of achieving the same using a webpack middleware, but is there another easier and better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

webpack dev-server is generally a simple Express or similar node.js server. It's essentially exactly the same as writing is on an express.js server.

`npm install mongoose mongodb --save-dev`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Replace with import as desired
const mongoConnectString = 'mongodb://localhost/database-name-here';

mongoose.connect(mongoConnectString, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Err, could not connect to the database.');
  }
});
```

Replace the mongoConnectString as needed for developing or using databases that aren't local to your machine.